# JAVA - Jpeg To Jpeg Steganography

Tags: java, image, steganography

I'm trying to create a software in Java for Steganography that receive an image in jpeg format, add secret text and create a steganographic image in jpeg format. After extract the secret text from the image in jpeg.

Basically I need to implement an algorithm that is resistant to JPEG compression and manipulation.

I have found on internet a lot of solution that use PNG format, but not in JPEG.

Is possible to make this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

JPEG is a lossy format by design. You'll get lossy (i.e. corrupted) steganographic data if you try to use it.

I suppose there could be a *theoretical* way to store data without losing it, but you'd need to understand the JPEG algorithm perfectly and be quite the wizard.

Comment: Thanks I'm trying to do this. Have you an example?

Comment: No, as I'm not a wizard and I have only a vague idea of the JPEG algorithm. Honestly it sounds like you shouldn't even bother trying (unless you're a wizard).